# How to run all wars modules in tomcat plugin of a multiple modules maven project?

Tags: maven, tomcat, module, tomcat7, war

I have a maven project containing multiple modules. I want to run all of the wars file with Tomcat plugin. However, only one war module is able to run. The remaining is not running. 
In parent pom I specify:

```
    <modules>
        <module>web-01</module>
        <module>web-02</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <finalName>mvn-multi-02</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>    
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>web-01</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <scope>compile</scope>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>web-02</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <scope>compile</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                    <configuration>
                        <webapps>
                            <webapp>
                                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                                <artifactId>web-01</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2</version>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                            </webapp>
                            <webapp>
                                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                                <artifactId>web-02</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0</version>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                            </webapp>
                        </webapps>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>

        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

When I run `mvn tomcat7:run` then only web-01 is running and I'm able to visit localhost:8080/web-01. If I changed the parent pom module order to

```
<modules>
    <module>web-02</module>
    <module>web-01</module>
</modules>
```

and run maven command again then the web-02 will be running. So, it only run the module declared first in `<modules> </modules>` tag.
Please help me to run all the war web at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you declare your wars as dependencies for a Maven plugin? I'm pretty sure it doesn't need them

Comment: If I remove dependencies then I still want to know how to run both war module with Tomcat plugin at the same time.